# Get the name of uploaded file as a variable in Shiny

Tags: r, file-upload, shiny

I am creating a Shiny App where one of the sections of a Venn Diagram will be named after the uploaded file(done by user). For example, if someone uploads a file ClientXYZ.csv, one section of the Venn diagram will be named "ClientXYZ"

Is it possible to do this in Shiny?

Comment: Yes it is possible in shiny. If you use file input in ui like  `fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",  accept = c( "text/csv", "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",  ".csv")` then in the server side you will get the filename as the following `input$file1$name`. Refer to this [link](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/fileInput.html)

Answer (score 5):

Its not clear without a reproducible example, but you can grab the name of the file with input and name.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

   titlePanel("Grabbing my file name"),

   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        fileInput('file1', 'Select your file',
                  accept = c(
                    'text/csv',
                    'text/comma-separated-values',
                    '.csv'
                  )
        )
      ),
      mainPanel(
         textOutput("myFileName")
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  file_name <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    return (stringi::stri_extract_first(str = inFile$name, regex = ".*(?=\\.)"))
  })

  output$myFileName <- renderText({ file_name() })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```