# Retrieve file information (name, size, rows and cols number) in Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I need a shiny app to retrieve some file information as filename, size, numbers of rows and columns. My final ideia it is to build a box that automatically shows the metadata and if I import another dataset, it updates too. The original code I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41505423/get-the-name-of-uploaded-file-as-a-variable-in-shiny), but I tried to modify. Any help? I am new in Shiny R.

```
    ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Grabbing my file name"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Select your file",
                multiple = FALSE,
                accept = c("text/csv",
                           "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                           ".csv",".xlsx")),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("myFileName"),
      textOutput("myFileSize"),
      textOutput("myFileRow"),
      textOutput("myFileCol"),

    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  file_name <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)){
      return(NULL)
      }else{
        return (inFile$name)
      }
  })
  output$myFileName <- renderText({ file_name() })

  file_size <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)){
      return(NULL)
    }else{
      return (file.size(inFile$name))
    }
  })
  output$myFileSize <- renderText({ file_size() })

  file_row <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)){
      return(NULL)
    }else{
      return (nrow(inFile))
    }
  })
  output$myFileRow <- renderText({ file_row() })

  file_col <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)){
      return(NULL)
    }else{
      return (ncol(inFile))
    }
  })
  output$myFileCol <- renderText({ file_col() })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get an error message? An unwanted behaviour?

Comment: My previous code was not returning all information that I need from my dataset, but it was already solved by Akrun. Thank you anyway, Alexandre Fenyo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to read the dataset to get the `ncol/nrow`.  It would be more efficient to read the data once and get the `ncol/nrow` (here we used `dim` to get that instead of repeating `ncol/nrow`.

```
library(shiny)
```

-ui

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Grabbing my file name"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file1', 'Select your file',
                accept = c(
                  'text/csv',
                  'text/comma-separated-values',
                  '.csv'
                )
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("myFileName"),
      textOutput("myFileSize"),
      textOutput("myFileColrow")

    )
  )
)
```

-server

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  file_name <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL) else return (tools::file_path_sans_ext(inFile$name))
  })     

  file_colrowsize <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)){
      return(NULL)
    }else{
     tmp <- read.csv(inFile$datapath)  
      return (list(dim(tmp), object.size(tmp)))
    }
  })      

  output$myFileName <- renderText({ file_name() })
  output$myFileColrow <- renderText({ file_colrowsize()[[1]] })
  output$myFileSize <- renderText({file_colrowsize()[[2]]})     

}
```

-Run the application

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Output from running

[image]

[image]

NOTE: We could also combine the two `reactive` into a single one and then return a `list` with 3 elements - 1) file name, 2) file size 3) dimensions

Comment: Thank you! That is what I was looking for! I will keep studying shiny, I still have a lot to learn! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you want an R solution, but I think your options are pretty limited if you only consider this.  How about an Excel-VBA solution.  Go to the link below and download the sample file.  That should do all you want, and a whole lot more.

http://learnexcelmacro.com/wp/2011/11/how-to-get-list-of-all-files-in-a-folder-and-sub-folders/